# What is postgresql select process?

Tags: linux, postgresql, process

we are using postgresql for our application.
after a time, idle CPU was less than 20%.
we understood select and idle process caused it, but we don't understand what does mean select process.
can anyone help we?

[image]

Comment: This looks like an output from ps.  Postgres provides limited information to ps, varying between platforms.  SELECT is the start of the postgres query last executed on the connection and ps probably doesn't have more information.  This page might be helpful: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/monitoring-ps.html

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL updates the process title to give a clue about what that backend is doing.  "SELECT" means it is currently working on an SQL SELECT statement.  If you want the details, log into PostgreSQL and look into the `pg_stat_activity` view.

The ones that are "idle" should not be consuming CPU at that moment.  The fact that they show up in `top` suggests that they have not been idle for long, but rather are rapidly cycling between some other state (probably SELECT) and idle.

Answer (score 1):

You should find out which statements are using your CPU. For that, employ the [`pg_stat_statements`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgstatstatements.html) extension.